# Spring batch Job execution iteraton using annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch without xml configuration. I want to create a Job that is composed by several steps and I want to make several iterations over the same job. So basically I want to create a flow composed by several steps, last step check a condition using listener and returns a status if the condition is satisfied the Job ends, if condition is not satisfied then it goes to first step.

I'm trying to create it programatically without no luck, I simplified it to the most simplest solution with two steps.

```
public class MyListener {

    int iterations = 0;

    @AfterStep
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if(3 > iterations) {
            iterations ++;
            return new ExitStatus("CONTINUE");
        }
        else {
            iterations=0;
            return new ExitStatus("FINISHED");
        }
    }
}
@Bean
public MyListener listener() {
    return new MyListener();
}
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").<Object, Object> chunk(1).reader(dummyReader())
            .processor(logItemProcessor()).writer(logItemWriter()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step step2() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").<Object, Object> chunk(1).reader(secondReader())
            .processor(logItemProcessor()).writer(logItemWriter()).listener(listener()).build();
}
@Bean
public Job jobtest2() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob2")
            .start(step())
            .next(step2()).on("CONTINUE").to(step()).on("FINISHED").end().build()
            .build();
}
```

This is my last atemp but id does not seems to work

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "without no luck"? What works, what does not work? Are the beans even picked up and injected somewhere? Where? How do you start the program? Is jobtest2() even called?

Comment: Don't use a listener, but a `JobExecutionDecider` to redirect job flow

Comment: Apologies this is a typo "with no luck". The beans was not injected in any other place. I started the job using joblauncher from rest service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what is wrong with my code, both steps has the same "step"

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").<Object, Object> chunk(1).reader(dummyReader())
            .processor(logItemProcessor()).writer(logItemWriter()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step step2() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2").<Object, Object> chunk(1).reader(secondReader())
            .processor(logItemProcessor()).writer(logItemWriter()).listener(listener()).build();
}
```

If I change the second bean "step2" it starts to work